# Where to catch a keyboard interrupt in asyncio: at code entry point or main function?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, python-asyncio, interrupt

I am working with a bluetooth `bleak` program using the `asyncio` module, and I'm trying to find a way to gracefully close the running tasks and event loop after a keyboard interrupt as well as save an array to a `txt` file before the program closes. I am not sure if the best place to try to catch an interrupt as at the entry point in the `if __name__ == "__main__` portion of the script or in the actual `main` function.

The entry point and main function like the following:

```
async def main(ADDRESS, OUTLET):
    try:
        async with BleakClient(ADDRESS) as client:
            tasks = [
                asyncio.ensure_future(run(client, True)),
            ]

            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG"] = str(1)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main(ADDRESS, OUTLET))
```

From what I've seen posted in other places, some signal interrupt handlers are placed in the entry point using the `try: except: finally` structure, while others place them in the `main` function.

Without writing a custom signal handler, it seems like it should be possible to use an `except` clause to `cancel()` all tasks in `loop` as well as print arrays to `txt` before exiting, but I'm unclear as to which of these two code sections (`if __name__` or `main()`) would be the place to put it. Any advice would be welcome. Thank you.